# How to parse the values between div id tag in WPF using HtmlAgility Pack?

Tags: c#, html, css, wpf

I have a html file like this:

```
<div id="id_1">
Some Texts 
</div>
<div id ="id_2">
Some Texts
</div>
```

How can I get all the texts between each div id tag? My question is related to WPF.

Here is my code:

```
private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("file.html");
    HtmlNode nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='id_1']");
    var text = nodes.InnerText;
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am scraping this source:

```
<div id="id_1">
   Some Texts 1
</div>
<div id ="id_2">
   Some Texts 2
</div>
```

using:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\temp\\stackhtml.html");
int i = 1;
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string text = node.InnerText; 
    Console.WriteLine("text" + i.ToString() + ": " + text);
    i++;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

result:

[image]

You can do with you want with the strings, populate and array, etc....